# Prove: If $\int_{\phi}\omega = \int_{\psi}\omega$ whenever $\phi$ and $\psi$ have the same endpoints, then $\omega=df$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

[image: EXERCISE]

This is an exercise that I have been assigned for homework. I don't really know how to approach it though. I know that $\int_{\phi}\omega$ only depends on the endpoints $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ where $\phi:[a,b]\to U$. I have considered the hint, but don't know what to do with it. It sounds almost definitional to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let me first elaborate on the hint. Let's take a one-form $\omega = g(x) \, dx$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Let $x_0$ be any point in $\mathbb{R}$. Define a function $f(x)$ by
$$f(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \omega = \int_{x_0}^x g(x) \, dx.$$
Here's a question for you: by the second fundamental theorem of calculus, what is $\frac{df}{dx}$? Using that, what is $df$?

Now let's go to $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Again, let $x_0$ be any point in $U$. Given $\omega$, let's try to define $f(x)$ in precisely the same way as above:
$$f(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \omega.$$
Here are a couple of things for you to think about:

1. What might $\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x$ possibly mean in this context, since there are many paths in $U$ joining $x_0$ and $x$?

*Edit:* Here's what you should do: let $f(x) = \displaystyle \int_{\phi_x} \omega$, where $\phi_x: [a,b] \to U$ is *any* path such that $\phi_x(a) = x_0$ and $\phi_x(b) = x$. Such a path exists because $U$ is connected. (We probably want $\phi_x$ to be piecewise smooth, but let's brush that under the rug.) The point is that it *doesn't matter* which path $\phi_x$ we choose, because of the property of $\omega$ that we were given. (Note that a different choice of the starting point $x_0$ would only change $f$ by a constant and thus not change $df$; do you see why?)

1. What is, say, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$, and what is $df$?

Comment: I was able to follow all of your points/questions except for the second to last one. I do have an idea of what $\int_{\phi}\omega$ is, where $\phi$ is a smooth parametrized curve, but I do not know how to translate that into an integral between 2 points.

Comment: Good question! You're right that to define the integral, you need a curve $\phi$. I have edited my answer with more details.